# ¿Como puedo imprimir un arreglo de forma entendible? PHP

Tags: php, array

Cuando utilizo `print_r($arreglo)` me imprime todo encimado, hay alguna manera de ordenar eso?

Comment: Podrías especificar más tu pregunta?, quizás de que se trata el arreglo que quieres imprimir tal vez.

Comment: usando `var_dump($arreglo);`

Comment: Si por todo encimado te refieres a que el arreglo se muestra sin formato, puedes usar el tag <pre> para dar formato de código al arreglo. Algo así: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($arreglo); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Gracias! @JuanPinzón

Comment: @JuanPinzón deberías ponerlo como respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola Intenta con esta opción `print("<pre>" . print_r($arreglo, true) . "</pre>");`

lo que yo normalmente hago es ponerlo en una función para luego poder reutilizarlo

```
function print_p($arreglo) {
    print("<pre>" . print_r($arreglo, true) . "</pre>");
}
```

Luego Solo la llamas en tu código y listo `print_p( $arreglo_de_matrices_u_objeto )`